# Grainy GUI on KDE plasma

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04

A lot of the GUI seems to be "grainy". It happens only when the panel is over another dark surface. A web browser with a white website opened would make start menu look just fine, from what I can tell.

Theme's Gently. It's pretty much a fresh 20.04 Kubuntu install.

How can I fix it?

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-40-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 24 × AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12-Core Processor
Memory: 31,4 GiB of RAM
```

## Update

Happens on other themes as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be with the graphics drivers.. i had a NVIDIA graphics card and used open source drivers and the issue occured, then i changed back to NVIDIA drivers and seems to have fixed it

Comment: Yeah, I was rolling nouveau

Comment: Actually, scratch that, it was a different machine. I was running official AMD drivers there.